# Twitter "View Summary" button

Tags: twitter, share, social-media

I noticed on Hollywood Reporter that within their tweets they have a "view summary" button, which when clicked on, gives you a preview of a post on their site with a title, excerpt, and preview picture.

[image]

Any clue as to where some documentation is on how to accomplish this? Ive browsed the [twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) for a bit and had no success finding anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Twitter To [Tweet More Interactive Content](http://www.socialbakers.com/blog/649-twitter-to-tweet-more-interactive-content/) by [Social Bakers](http://www.socialbakers.com)

*"We followed the Wall Street Journal on Twitter to see how it works. When the Tweet contains a link to an article on its website, you will see the View Summary option instead of Expand. The summary will provide you with the article´s preview, sometimes even Twitter accounts of the publishers and writers. And when you click anywhere on the preview, you will get navigated to the article on the website. The number of retweets and favorites will appear as before. You can continue to read the article, follow these accounts, reply, favorite or retweet the Tweet just as you are used to."*

Apparently all you need is a link to your content. However, I'm sure there's more to this because it doesn't *always* seem to work.

** EDIT **

It's actually called a *Twitter Card* and here is the [documentation for Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards)

Comment: +1 Was looking for this info. Related question for Google+ and Facebook: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25941/29263